# Bootstrap valign content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple piece of code that I am trying to get vertically aligned.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3kj44net/

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="header-tool-title">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-5 vcenter">
            <h1 class="toolTitle"><span name="el_toolName">Tool Name</span> <small class="toolSubTitle">#<span name="el_toolID">244</span></small></h1>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-7 vcenter">
            <span class="pull-right toolStatus">
               <span class="pull-right">
                  <h4 class="text-right"><span name="el_toolStatus"><a data-content-type="manageDeprecation" name="route">Scheduled for Deprecation</a></span></h4>
               </span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

In the image below, I want the text on the right to be on the same level as the text on the left.

I tried adding a `verticle-align` attribute to the content but it still wouldn't move.

Thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to have both columns the same size and

```
margin-top:auto;
```

on the element you want to push to the bottom.

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3kj44net/6/